# Add an additional axes to seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a retention matrix as a seaborn heatmap. I was wondering, where and how I could add an additional axis. I want to have an additional vertical bar chart next to the heatmap to show the number of new users in a given cohort. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

I tried using fig.add_axes, but am somewhat lost as to what parameters and what values to use.
Cheers

```
parameter = 'Total Rent'
recordtpye = 'Tenant'

dataset = df[(df['Account Record Type'] == recordtpye)]
grouped = dataset.groupby(['TenanatCohort','BookingPeriod'])

cohorts = grouped.agg({'Request ID': pd.Series.nunique,'Total Rent':np.sum})
cohorts.rename(columns={'Request ID': 'Number of Bookings'}, inplace=True)
cohorts.reset_index(inplace=True)
cohorts.set_index(['TenanatCohort', 'BookingPeriod'], inplace=True)

cohort_group_size = dataset.groupby('TenanatCohort').agg({'Tenant: Account Name': pd.Series.nunique})

user_retention_numbers = cohorts[parameter].unstack(0)

bookings_per_cohort = \
cohorts.reset_index()\
.groupby('TenanatCohort')\
.agg({parameter: np.sum})[parameter]\
.divide(cohort_group_size['Tenant: Account Name'])

inp = user_retention_numbers

sns.set(style='white')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,7))

graph = sns.heatmap(inp.T,
                    mask=inp.T.isnull(),
                    cmap="Blues",
                    annot=True,
                    fmt=".0f",
                    annot_kws={"size":10});
graph.set_xlabel("Booking Period")
graph.set_ylabel("Cohort Group")

plt.yticks(rotation=0)
```

Comment: As usual, it would be useful if you would provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (i.e. that does not rely on your particular dataset). Furthermore, please provide a mockup of the desired ouput. What kind of "vertical chart" are you trying to plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seaborn's `heatmap` is an axis level function, meaning that you can create whatever axes you want beforehand, and pass a reference to the Axes object you want seaborn to use when calling `heatmap`.

```
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(6,4), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':(5,1)})
sns.heatmap(uniform_data, ax=ax1)
ax2.plot([1,2],[3,4], 'ro-')
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! this should get me there! Sorry for not providing more data.